# Why this code doesn't work

Tags: java

my code is for menu. In the exit case of the menu it must count how many times are used options 1 and 2. No matter how many times I choose 1 and 2, when I choose 3 it gives me 0 for counter1 and counter2 and I can't find out why.

The code for passive class:

```
    public final class Service {

    private int x;

    public Service(int x) {
    setX(x);
    }

    public double getX() {
    return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    }
    public void displayMenu() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {

        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.printf("%s", "Choose number\n"
            + "1.business account \n"
            + "2.Account for person\n"
            + "3.Exit\n"
    );

    }

    public void doSelection(int choice) {

    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            counter1++;
            ServiceNumber newNumber = new ServiceNumber(1,1);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, newNumber.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                System.out.println();
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            counter2++;
            ServiceNumber newNumber2 = new ServiceNumber(2,2);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, newNumber2.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {

                System.out.println();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
        System.out.printf("How many times have you chosen option 1 %d\n"
                    + "How many times have you chosen option2: %d\n",
                    counter1, counter2);
            System.exit(0);
            break;

    }

    }

    public void getUserChoice() {
    do {
        displayMenu();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        choice = input.nextInt();

        while (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter new code");
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }

        doSelection(choice);
    } while (true);
```

The active class:

```
   public class ServiceTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Service newNumber=new Service(0);   
   newNumber.getUserChoice();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are local variables.

```
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
```

will be reset every call to `doSelection().`

declare them outside of the method to maintain state between calls.

```
public void doSelection(int choice) {

int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
```

should be changed to

```
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;

public void doSelection(int choice) {
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review! Please see: [How do I write a good answer?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), where you will find: [Not all questions can or should be answered here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Save yourself some frustration by flagging off-topic questions for closure instead.

Comment: Okay.. so code review for review of working code.. this one should have been on stack overflow instead..